# Phonegap Android facebook plugin crashes

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am getting the error below when I try to login through facebook plugin for Android.

The app basically crashes "stopped", Any ideas will be appreciated.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {xxx/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f060012
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f060012
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:314)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:327)
        at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.onCreate(WebDialog.java:189)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:355)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:260)
        at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$WebViewAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:471)
        at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:214)
        at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:193)
        at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(AuthorizationClient.java:121)
        at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:102)
        at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:113)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
        ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i kinda resolved it, i deleted the app_id string.  turns out facebook plugin doesn't use that.